# How to use TypeInformation in a generic method using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I'm trying to create a generic method in Apache Flink to parse a DataSet[String](JSON strings) using case classes. I tried to use the TypeInformation like it's mentioned here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/types_serialization.html#generic-methods

I'm using liftweb to parse the JSON string, this is my code:

```
import net.liftweb.json._
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._

class Loader(settings: Map[String, String])(implicit environment: ExecutionEnvironment) {

  val env: ExecutionEnvironment = environment

  def load[T: TypeInformation](): DataSet[T] = {

    val data: DataSet[String] = env.fromElements(
      """{"name": "name1"}""",
      """{"name": "name2"}"""
    )

    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

    data.map(item => parse(item).extract[T])

  }
}
```

But I got the error:

```
No Manifest available for T
data.map(item => parse(item).extract[T])
```

Then I tried to add a Manifest and delete the TypeInformation like this:

```
def load[T: Manifest](): DataSet[T] = { ...
```

And I got the next error:

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[T]
```

I'm very confuse about this, I'll really appreciate your help.
Thanks.